# Limit contact form emails per second/minute

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I recently made a portfolio website and put it online on `000webhost.com`. Today when I logged in, the account was suspended because someone sent more then 70 emails in a minute via my contact form - something that the webhosting does not allow.

I am looking for some way to stop this from hapening again. I used both php and javascript/jquery for form validation.

This is my curent php validation code.

```
$firstName = $_POST["firstName"];
$lastName = $_POST["lastName"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
$to = "fox.team001@gmail.com";
$subject = $firstName . " " . $lastName;
$headers = "From: " .$firstName . " " . $lastName . "\r\nReply-To:" . $email;

 if(validateEmail($email)){
     @mail($to , $subject , $message , $headers);

 }

validate($firstName , $lastName , $email , $message);
function validate ($firstName , $lastName , $email , $message){
    if(!empty($firstName) && !empty($lastName)  && !empty($email) && !empty($message)){
        if(validateEmail($email)){
            header("refresh:5; url=http://www.foxteam.net");
        }else{
           header("refresh:0; url=http://www.foxteam.net/contact.php");
        }
    }else{
       header("refresh:0; url=http://www.foxteam.net/contact.php");
    }
}   
function validateEmail($email) {
    $pattern = "^[A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+\@[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9]+$";
    if(preg_match("/{$pattern}/", $email)) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how can I stop spammers to send spam emails?

Comment: Why not include their IP address in the PHP script and limit their usage to a certain number per hour?

Comment: Do a two-step form. Most spammers only submit the first form, but not the second. You also give users the possibility to review their text before sending it. While doing that you can also do captcha or javascript tests, something most spambots can't do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very hard to stop spam coming through a contact form completely, however there are a number of methods you can use to reduce it, some of which include:

1. **Use a honeypot** - the idea behind this is to have a hidden field on your form with a generic name (e.g. `answer`), if this field has anything in it, then don't bother sending the email (but still tell the user that the email has been sent) - it is obviously spam as there is no other way the field could have been filled out.
2. **IP limiting** - store the user's IP address somewhere and limit the number of emails per minute/hour that each IP address can send.
3. **Word filtering** - have a list of words, if any are found then don't send the email (usualy words like *viagra*, *penis*, etc).
4. **CAPTCHA**, to me, this is a last resort. If you do use one, implement [recaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha), it is by far the best one around. But as I say, use this as a last resort, there are plenty of other methods you can use without annoying the users of your website.

Comment: In case of honeypot does it mean that spam bots can populate hidden fields as well?

Comment: Usually bots will populate all fields of a form - which is why a honeypot works. However there are bots smart enough to detect if the field is hidden or not, and so bypass the honeypot. So don't only use a honeypot, it's just a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) to block robot spammers

Answer (score 0):

put your **if()** condition into for loop which contains range 70 and then send email only. if it will over by 70 then put it over **else** part with some suitable message

Thanks

Comment: That will only work if you're using the same instance of the script to send emails; it won't help at all if the script is being called multiple times from multiple places.